# Кем очищается память в стеке?

Tags: память, стек, куча

Ни в одном источнике на нашла ответ конкретно на этот вопрос. Место под значимый тип очищается, когда он покидает контекст, но чем очищается? Не сборщиком мусора. Самим стеком?

Comment: Или сборщиком мусора, или Вашим кодом, который будет очищать. Сам стек явно не делает ничего, это же просто такой формат записи данных

Comment: Для стэка нет понятия очищается вроде как. Разве что перезаписывает старые значения на новые

Comment: Стек - это массив `stack` и число - вершина стека `top`. Вершина перемещается вверх-вниз - `top += 1`, `top -= 1`. Данные пишутся в массив `stack[top] = value` и читаются из него `value = stack[top]`. Массив фиксированного размера, он существует всё время пока работает программа. Его не надо "очищать".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Память в стеке очищается автоматически при выходе из функции или блока, где была выделена эта память. Это делается благодаря технологии, называемой управлением памятью стека.

Когда программа входит в функцию или блок, стек выделяет память для локальных переменных, которые используются в этой функции или блоке.

Когда программа выходит из функции или блока, стек автоматически очищает эту выделенную память, восстанавливая ее для дальнейшего использования. Это достигается за счет того, что стек отслеживает местоположение своего "указателя" и когда функция завершается, указатель возвращается к месту, где он был до вызова функции. Это гарантирует, что вся память, выделенная в стеке во время выполнения функции, будет освобождена и не будет вызывать утечку памяти.

Конкретно очищает память стека сам интерпретатор или виртуальная машина, в зависимости от языка и используемого окружения. Например, в случае языка Java, это виртуальная машина Java (JVM), которая отвечает за управление памятью стека. В случае с C или C++, это компилятор или интерпретатор, который генерирует код, который реализует управление памятью стека.

В общем, это система управления памятью которая включена в язык или окружение и которая отвечает за очистку памяти стека автоматически.

Comment: в си память на стеке не освобождается как мне кажется

Comment: хм. из-за наличие декструктора? но мы же про метод говорим в вопросе

Comment: откуда в си деструкторы? в вопросе так все абстрактно. вот классический пример `strtok` - вызываем первый раз со строкой, а потом вызываем несколько раз с null. вроде функция завершилась, но указатель на кусок строки всё ещё на стеке и при следующем вызове.

Comment: strtok использует статическую переменную, которая хранит указатель на текущую позицию разбиения строки. после первого вызова со строкой, эта переменная запоминает позицию, на которой остановился последний вызов, и при следующих вызовах с null, функция использует эту переменную, чтобы продолжить разбиение строки с этой позиции. поэтому указатель на стеке и при следующем вызове он используется функцией

Comment: Переменная с указателей на буфер эта на стеке и никуда не пропадает

Comment: в функции `strtok` есть переменная `static char *last` и только потому она и сохраняется, что `static`

Answer (score 1):

Такой вариант также возможен. Мы о каком языке и о какой его реализации?

Память на стеке не очищается и не возвращается. Ни куда не течет потому что функция при вызове использует всегда один и тот же адрес и размер. Выделяется стек на этапе компиляции. Занимает свой размер в памяти при запуске.

Comment: на этапе компиляции определяется необходимый функции размер стека, сама же память в стеке выделяется при вызове функции увеличением указателя вершины стека на нужный размер. Иначе, как бы работала рекурсия

Comment: спасибо за исправление